# MS Visual Studio 2015 RAM usage creeping up, even on new machine

Tags: windows-7, memory, visual-studio-2015

One of the developers has an issue with her machine (Win7 x64 Pro, 16 GB's RAM, Core i7 CPU, 500 GB SSD, etc) where RAM usage keeps "creeping up" after a few hours. **Usage gets up to around 10 GB's (of 16 GB physical RAM available) then she is forced to close/reopen Visual Studio.**

We replaced her machine, but somehow the issue followed her. All the other devs use VS '15 without issue, so it must be something unique to her. However, she says she is not using ReShaper or CodeLens and stated "I only have the necessary extensions like TypeScript."

What could be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: Does the problem appear in new projects or only in old ones?

Comment: Have this developer remove all extensions as a test

Comment: Thank you, @nullterminatedstring. I believe she is only working on "old" projects that were already on the last machine, but I will double-check.

Comment: I'm being told that so much code gets reused that effectively *all* projects should be considered "old." Also, she tells me that she has already disabled all extensions that she can.

Comment: So this developer is running with ZERO add-ons?

Comment: I don't know yet, she just said she has already disabled all but the essential (default maybe?) ones. She thinks Win10 might solve this, but there are plenty of devs still on 7 that don't have this issue, many with the exact same model Dell Precision workstation even.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I'm not a dev and have never used Visual Studio, so am learning as I go with this ticket.

Comment: vs2015 is a 32bit with large address aware to be use 4GB. so the 10Gb come from something else.